# Error de conexión de Entity Framework con postgresql

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-6

el día de hoy, estoy tratando de utilizar entity framework con postgresql utilizando el **dll npgsql**, este lo descargué del nuget junto con el **EntityFramework6.npgsql**, al crear la conexión desde el wizard de Entity Framework, todo funciona, pero al tratar de hacer una simple consulta, devuelva la siguiente excepción:

> The ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'Npgsql' is either not registered in the machine or application config file, or could not be loaded. See the inner exception for details.

Por ahí leí que se podía deber a varíos proveedores en el app.config, pero aún no funciona, les dejo el código de mi config:

```
<configuration>
<configSections>
<!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
<section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
</configSections>
<startup>
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
</startup>
<entityFramework>
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
<providers>
  <!--<provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />-->
  <provider invariantName="Npgsql" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlServices, EntityFramework6.Npgsql" />
</providers>
</entityFramework>
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
<dependentAssembly>
<assemblyIdentity name="Npgsql" publicKeyToken="5d8b90d52f46fda7" 
culture="neutral" />
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.2.7.0" newVersion="3.2.7.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
<connectionStrings>
<add name="Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/POSTGRESQL.csdl|res://*/POSTGRESQL.ssdl|res://*/POSTGRESQL.msl;provider=Npgsql;provider connection string=&quot;Host=localhost;Database=*****;Username=******;Password=******&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Gracias de ante mano por la ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aparentemente tenía que agregar este código al app.config y se arregló todo.

```
<system.data>
<DbProviderFactories>
<add name="Npgsql Data Provider" invariant="Npgsql" description=".Net Data Provider for PostgreSQL" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7"/>
</DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

Comment: ¿Es el config de tu capa de presentación?

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta. Si lo que preguntas es si lo coloqué en el config de mi capa de presentación pues si, y también en la capa de modelo de datos.

Comment: Si eso era lo que te preguntaba. Ya solucione el problema que tenía.

Comment: Excelente, me alegro. Disculpa que no contesté antes. deberías editar la respuesta si encontraste otra manera de resolverlo!

Comment: Mi problema en si era que tenía que actualizar el Entity Framework a la ultima versión tanto en mi capa de datos como la de presentación claro que agregando antes el código  que compartes.